# xstream deserialization issue

Tags: xml, xstream, xml-deserialization

Trying to de-serialized the following XML, where "day" & "fulldob" are objects
types with their individual converters for custom logic. Once De-serialized & when toXML
method is applied to the object, the values for "day" & "fulldob" are missing. Meaning, day & fulldob are not getting de-serialized properly. Can someone please help?

**************** input XML *****************

```
 <primarydob>
   <month>05</month>
   <day>13</day>
   <year>1982</year>
  <fulldob>19820513</fulldob>
 </primarydob>
```

****** XML from Object (after de-serializing the above XML) *****************

```
 <primarydob>
   <month>05</month>
   <day/>
   <year>1982</year>
   <fulldob/>
 </primarydob>
```

Here's the object for "primarydob"

```
@XStreamAlias("dob")   
public class DOBData {

  @XStreamAlias("month")
  private String month;

  @XStreamAlias("day")
  private DOBDay dobDay = new DOBDay();

  @XStreamAlias("year")
  private String year;

  @XStreamAlias("fulldob")
  private FullDOB fulldob = new FullDOB();

  getters/setters
}
```

Here's the object for "fulldob"

```
@XStreamAlias("fulldobdata")
@XStreamConverter(FullDOBDayMaskingConverter.class)
public class FullDOB {

  @XStreamAlias("fulldob")
  private String fullDOB;

  public String getFullDOB() {
      return fullDOB;
  }

  public void setFullDOB(String fullDOB) {

      this.fullDOB = fullDOB;
  }
}
```

Here's the object for "day"

```
@XStreamAlias("dobday")
@XStreamConverter(DOBDayMaskingConverter.class)
public class DOBDay {

  @XStreamAlias("day")
  private String day;

  public String getDay() {
         return day;
  }
  public void setDay(String day) {
         this.day = day;
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DOBDayConverter code:

```
public class DOBDayConverter extends ReflectionConverter {
    public DOBDayConverter(XStream xstream) {
        super(xstream.getMapper(), xstream.getReflectionProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object obj, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        DOBDay d = (DOBDay) obj;
        try {
            writer.setValue(d.getDay());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,UnmarshallingContext context) {
        DOBDay day = new DOBDay();

        day.setDay(reader.getValue());

        return day;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(DOBDay.class); 
    }

}
```

and here is the FullDOBConverter code:

```
public class FullDOBConverter extends ReflectionConverter {
    public FullDOBConverter(XStream xstream) {
        super(xstream.getMapper(), xstream.getReflectionProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object obj, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        FullDOB fd = (FullDOB) obj;
        try {
            writer.setValue(fd.getFullDOB());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,UnmarshallingContext context) {
        FullDOB fd = new FullDOB();

        fd.setFullDOB(reader.getValue());

        return fd;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(FullDOB.class); 
    }

}
```

Don't forget to register the converters and process the annotations:

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.processAnnotations(DOBData.class);
xs.processAnnotations(FullDOB.class);
xs.processAnnotations(DOBDay.class);
xs.registerConverter(new DOBDayConverter(xs));
xs.registerConverter(new FullDOBConverter(xs));
```